What protection is most suitable for a relay circuit with an unspecified load (DC coil, AC load)?
What measures can be taken to protect the relay itself and handle electrical surges and spikes in an industrial environment?
Typically, I place a flyback diode on the coil to prevent back EMF. In one circuit, we've used an NTC to prevent inrush current. The use of snubbers, varistors, Zener diodes, opto-couplers and other components is also commonly recommended.
Usually, the recommended circuits depend on the type of load (inductive, capacitive, or resistive), but what method can be a suitable option for designing a relatively general circuit when specific information about the type of load is not available?
I should also add that I mean a relay with a DC coil and an AC output load.
I would appreciate it if a suggested schematic could be provided in the response.


Just to be clear, you are asking on both coil side and contact side separately? The NTC or opto, on coil, or contacts? Why would coil have inrush current?

@Justme, Yes, I included both sides in one question so that a comprehensive summary can be provided. An optocoupler is used on the coil side, and an NTC is used on the contact side. If you have any recommendations for each side, I would appreciate it if you could provide them.

The optocoupler on coil side almost never does anything useful, so you'd have to draw a schematic how you used it.

The use of an optocoupler for the relay circuit control section was discussed in a separate thread, and it was determined that without ground separation, it does not help. In the text, I only mentioned common methods and asked what the most suitable method is, and I didn't specify anything myself. The picture is just an initial circuit for driving the relay, which I hope will be completed in this thread.

For the coil side, the single diode for catching the back-EMF is usually the simplest and worst possible method, as the coil current is only dissipated by the diode forward voltage, so the current and magnetic field takes long to decay, and the force to release the coil drops slowly, so the contacts may open slowly, with increasing contact resiatance first, and arcing for some time until contacts have traveled far enough.
Any other method of dissipating the coil back-EMF current is faster which will open the contacs in less time, stronger force, and faster contact movement speed. The zener and diode in series should be simple enough solution recommended by many relay manufacturers for DC driven coils.
For the contacts, it's more difficult to make a generic solution. Resistive loads need no special handling. Capacitive loads need inrush current limiting. Inductive loads need the back-EMF snubbed. Difference is also if loads are DC or AC. If DC and polarity can be assumed, a diode or better solution can be used, as long as you can guarantee the polarity and voltage being less than what diode can handle. If AC, diode is out of the question and there should be an RC snubber. However RC snubber over contacts is problematic, as now you have AC leakage current through the snubber even if relay contacts are off. The RC snubber might be placed over the load instead of contacts, but then that's not what you as a relay board maker can enforce except in documentation.
The best results are always achieved by some system integrator/designer knowing what kind of relay board will be connected to what kind of load, and then providing the correct method of protection given the load type and used voltages/currents with DC and/or AC. This also allows the relay contacts to be plain and simple dry contacts so any existing protection on the relay board does not limit the relay usage for various different purposes.
From that I suppose that for switching standard AC mains devices, they are sufficiently well made so they limit their own capacitive inrush and snub their own back-EMF with capacitor. The best thing could be to just put a RC snubber over the coil, but it will pass leakage and light loads like cheap LED lamps may light up dimly or start blinking after they turn on when input capacitor has charged enough.

Thanks. What about using MOVs?
